# Using "android.test.refunded" with in-app billing v3

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to test refunds in my application. From what I understand, this is done using the `android.test.refunded` product ID. I'm supposed to purchase this product, and then when querying the inventory I should find the item with a `REFUNDED` purchase state, consume it, and do whatever I need to do to reflect the change in the application.

This Does not work, purchasing `android.test.refunded` returns `null` purchase data and a `null` data signature, meaning not purchase has occurred. This causes the `IabHelper` to throw an error and exit. What is the right way of using this product ID?